# VBA Function is not showing up nor is it working

Tags: vba, function

Please look; my simple VBA function is not showing up:

```
Function master(sega)
    master(sega) = WorksheetFunction.SumIf([sega], "<80")
End Function
```

Comment: Needs more context.  What are you passing into it, and how are you calling it?  Should be `master = ...` and not `master(sega) = ...`

Comment: im try to call it as a manual function like typing it into excel  =master and then using my mouse to select the data

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub SumifTest()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")

Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = ws.Range("A:C")

Dim x As Double

x = Master(Rng)
    Debug.Print x

End Sub


Function Master(Sega As Range)

    Master = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Sega, "< 80")

End Function
```

Comment: I created a new sheet and new excel object for this code the function doesnt work,

Comment: You need to copy paste the function section of the code to your VBA editor.  Then the formula "Master" will be present in the excel sheet. When you type =Master("your range), It will provide you the answer.