# VBA Function Sumif

Tags: vba, function

```
Function master(sega)
    master(sega) = WorksheetFunction.SumIf([sega], "<80")
End Function
```

I can't call this function. Can someone make it work?

Comment: Please edit your first question instead of asking a new one: [Vba function not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33312903/vba-function-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Function master(sega)
    master = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(sega, "<80")
End Function
```

Comment: Where have you put the function?  I've just created it in a new module and it works just fine.

Comment: after an end sub. I cant call it through excel. (the name of the function doesnt show up)

Comment: In VBA IDE, right click on your VBProject and Insert>Module.  Add the code above into that module and you should be able to use in Excel.

Comment: yeah i was putting it in one of the sheets instead of the modules? I dont know why it wasnt working in the sheets.